# Iphone OS 3.1 vs 3.2 plus UIView background image display issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a Navigation controller in my app that pushes my homeview on load. The Home View has a subView which actually has the content (I plan to put another iAdBannerView later). The contentView(SubView) has a background image which is aligned with some text/label on the view to give a better look. Everything displays correctly in simulator (3.2 and higher versions).

I installed this in a 3.1 iphone device last night and it looks like the background image gets cut off from the top. It is almost like the view started at the correct position (after navigation bar) but the background image started from the top.

There is unfortunately no simulator for iOS 3.1 so I'm not able to reproduce this anywhere except the device. Even if I could reproduce, i'm not sure how to fix this because everything seems to be set up correctly. Is it a bug in 3.1. If anyone has experienced anything like this, could you please share?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what really happened. but I was able to change the height property of the content view to 520 or so and it started working fine.